# Relationship between impulse response output and input in discrete systems and signals

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, impulse-response

Does the equality $H(n_{f}) = \frac{Y(n_{f})}{X(n_{f})}$ hold  for discrete signals in the discrete Fourier domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If $Y(z)$, $H(z)$ and $X(z)$ are the $\mathcal Z$-Transform of the filter output, impulse-response and input, respectively, we have:

$Y(z) = H(z)X(z)$

Assuming a single-input single-output filter, the above functions are all scalars, so you can rearrange the equation as $H(z) = Y(z)/X(z)$. In particular for any complex $n_f$ you have $H(n_f) = Y(n_f)/X(n_f)$

Comment: so it does hold correct?

Comment: Correct, I used a more verbose language just to make explicit the assumptions you omitted in the original post.

Comment: what the heck is "$n_f$"?

Comment: Who knows? hehehe

Comment: $f$ for "frequency" ??

Comment: what's the "$n$" for?

Comment: maybe $$ n_f \triangleq e^{j 2 \pi f / f_\mathrm{s}} $$?